# AWS S3 downloads all from a bucket when I specify what to download specifically. Behaves different in bash shell than command line

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

So I'm trying to execute this (obfuscated for security) command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/subfolder/ /storage/ --recursive --exclude '*' --include 'a.data' --include 'b.data' --include 'c.data' .... and so on.
```

When I run this from the command line, everything works as expected.

However, when I run a bash shell that should run that command, aws tries to download all the files in that subfolder. I have checked with ps and found the exact command being used!

```
ubuntu   1761765  114  2.3 1206204 93252 pts/3   Sl+  18:47   0:06 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/aws s3 cp s3://buckt/subfolder/ /storage/ --recursive --exclude '*' --include 'a.data' --include 'b.data' --include 'c.data' ....
```

I get the same thing even when I simply run this:

```
ubuntu   1761765  114  2.3 1206204 93252 pts/3   Sl+  18:47   0:06 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/aws s3 cp s3://buckt/subfolder/ /storage/ --recursive --exclude '*'
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? It's like its ignoring everything after --recursive.

I have tried modifying my command, using ps to find what is actually being executed, and checking to make sure the correct user is running the command.

I am ultimately trying to build a long --include 'filename' string to download many files at once. Using bash for loops is way too slow.

Edit: Here is my bash script more or less:

```
includeList="--exclude '*' --recursive "
while [ $i -ne $cnt ] # while i != count
do
    #download the ith files
    f=${allFiles[$i]}
    includeList="${includeList}--include '$f' "
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
    mod=$(($i%10))
    if [ $mod -eq 0 ]; then
       aws s3 cp s3://bucket/$1/ /storage/ ${includeList}
       exit 0
    fi
 done
```

Comment: How are you running the command in the script?  I'd expect to see `*` in the PS output, not `'*'` that'll match nothing.

Comment: I've updated with my bash script. Running without quotes expands the * into all the items in the active directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` that you're passing to the AWS CLI is not meant to be globed by the shell.  Normally, quoting it is enough, but since you're including it in a variable, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
# Only quote the asterisk once here
includeList="--exclude * --recursive "
while [ $i -ne $cnt ] # while i != count
do
    #download the ith files
    f=${allFiles[$i]}
    includeList="${includeList}--include $f "
    i=$(( $i + 1 ))
    mod=$(($i%10))
    if [ $mod -eq 0 ]; then
        # Disable globbing explicitly, call aws, then turn globbing back on:
        set -f
        aws s3 cp s3://bucket/$1/ /storage/ ${includeList}
        set +f
        exit 0
    fi
 done
```

Comment: Yeah this was basically my problem. Good solution. I was able to exploit common data patterns in filenames to do a xx* instead, but this works better obviously.